# Generate a file hash similar to the one output by nix-prefetch-url

Tags: hash, nix

Suppose i've got a zip file available under some URL. I need to get its hash, which should be identical to the one output by `nix-prefetch-url --unpack <URL>`, but without a working Nix installation. How can one do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no easy way, as `nix-prefetch-url` adds the file to the store. More details here: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/generate-a-file-hash-similar-to-the-one-output-by-nix-prefetch-url/19907 (many thanks to prompt and thorough community member's response)

Answer (score 0):

Use Docker.

Demo:

```
$ nix-prefetch-url --unpack https://github.com/hraban/git-hly/archive/06ff628d5f2b02d1a883c94b01d58187d117f4f3.tar.gz
path is '/nix/store/gxx1pfp19s3a39j6gl0xw197b4409cmp-06ff628d5f2b02d1a883c94b01d58187d117f4f3.tar.gz'
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
$ # Or .zip: it's the same, because of --unpack:
$ nix-prefetch-url --unpack https://github.com/hraban/git-hly/archive/06ff628d5f2b02d1a883c94b01d58187d117f4f3.zip
path is '/nix/store/1bpjlzknnmq1x3hq213r44jwag1xkaqs-06ff628d5f2b02d1a883c94b01d58187d117f4f3.zip'
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
```

Download to a local directory

```
$ cd "$(mktemp -d)"
$ curl -sSL --fail https://github.com/hraban/git-hly/archive/06ff628d5f2b02d1a883c94b01d58187d117f4f3.tar.gz | tar xz
$ cd *
```

And test it:

```
$ # Using the modern nix command:
$ nix hash path --base32 .
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
$ # Or the same, using nix-hash:
$ nix-hash --type sha256 --base32 .
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
```

Same in Docker:

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/data nixos/nix nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command hash path --base32 /data
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/data nixos/nix nix-hash --type sha256 --base32 /data
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
```

P.S.: I'm not a huge fan of nix-prefetch-url's default output (base32). The default output of `nix hash path` is better, if you can use it:

```
$ nix hash path .
sha256-FibesuhNC4M81Gku9qLg4MsgS/qSZ2F3y4aa2u72j5g=
$ # Sanity check:
$ nix-hash --type sha256 --to-base32 $(<<<"FibesuhNC4M81Gku9qLg4MsgS/qSZ2F3y4aa2u72j5g=" base64 -d | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"' )
164gyvpdm6l6rdvn2rwjz95j1jz0w2igcbk9shy862sdx2rdw9hn
```